# Raster image display in a MapServer WMS

Tags: wms, mapserver

I am trying to display raster image using MapServer but it is not displaying anything, page is blank

My map file code is:

```
MAP      
NAME "ny_pop"
SHAPEPATH "C:\ms4w\apps\webgis\mpgaps"       
EXTENT 8240841.450745 2400319.900386 9218007.463612 3107183.406947
SIZE  450 500
STATUS OFF
DEBUG ON
IMAGETYPE "png"

PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:900913"
END

OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME "png"
  DRIVER AGG/PNG
  MIMETYPE "image/png"
  IMAGEMODE RGB
  EXTENSION "png"
  FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=0.75"
END

WEB             
    METADATA
        "wms_title" "WMS Pop Tif"
        "wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost:8085/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=map&map=C:\ms4w\apps\webgis\mpgaps\raster.map"            
        "wms_enable_request"  "GetMap GetFeatureInfo GetCapabilities"
    END
END

###########
LAYER
    NAME "ny_pop"
    DATA "094_056_d_26mar2012_516_12-mar-08.tif"
    STATUS OFF
    TYPE RASTER   
    METADATA
        "wms_title" "WMS NY Raster"
        "wms_srs" "EPSG:900913"
    END
END

###########
```

END

Data path is C:\ms4w\apps\webgis\mpgaps

Comment: Is the data (094_056_d_26mar2012_516_12-mar-08.tif) in EPSG:900913 projection?  Do you have a definition for 900913  in your epsg file?  Does

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the following line:

`"wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost:8085/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=map&map=C:\ms4w\apps\webgis\mpgaps\raster.map"`

Change that to:

`"wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost:8085/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\apps\webgis\mpgaps\raster.map"`

The `mode=map&` option is not correct for a WMS